# Why can an ifstream object be compared to 0?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get back into learning C++ after having first learned the basics about 20 years ago but then setting it aside.  I started by picking up a book I had learned from, back then.  Here's one of his examples (I've already figured out that it has some obsolete syntax):

```
#include <fstream.h>
void main() {
    ifstream infile("iocopy.cpp");
    if (!infile) cerr << "couldn't open iopcopy.cpp" << endl;
    ... other junk
}
```

His explanation of the `!` operator on `infile` was that it "checks to see if the object is nonzero", which was confusing to me (what does it mean for an object to be zero?).  So I decided to try it myself:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
void main () {
    std::ifstream f ("something");
//  if (f == 0) std::cout << "Couldn't open file" << std::endl;
    if (!f) std::cout << "Couldn't open file" << std::endl;
}
```

This works as expected, displaying a message if the file doesn't exist and nothing if it does.  It also works if I uncomment the line with `(f == 0)` and comment out the following line.

I think I figured out the `!` operator here; I found `operator!` in one of the header files defined to return a `fail` field.  I'm confused about why the first example `(f == 0)` works, though, since I didn't see any `operator==` that would seem to apply.

So what's going on?  Can any variable of any class type be compared to 0?  Is there something special about `ifstream` that variables of that type are essentially pointers (that could be compared to null or 0)?  Or is there an `operator==` redefinition that I missed somewhere?  I'm more used to languages like Java where it's impossible for a constructor to return a null value, so I'm confused.

Comment: `int main()`, not `void`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C++03**

`basic_ios` (a base class of `ifstream`) has an `operator void*` which makes it implicitly convertible to `void*`.

`0` is a valid value for a `void*` literal, so you are comparing values of type `void*`.

**C++11**

`basic_ios` (a base class of `ifstream`) has an `explicit operator bool` which makes it convertible to `bool` only by an explicit cast. So your example should not compile.

`bool` is implicitly convertible to `int` as per the C++ language type conversion rules, so if the `operator bool` had not been `explicit`, then you would be comparing values of type `int`.

Comment: "implicitly convertible to bool"... I don't think so.  It's [supposed to be explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and use contextual conversion.

Comment: In C++11, the conversion to `bool` is not implicit, but rather `explicit` -- update: not only by explicit casts, the explicit conversion to `bool` can also be triggered by context: `if (f)` will use the explicit conversion to `bool`

Comment: The version I used is from 2008, and I do see `operator void*` but not `operator bool`.

Answer (score 3):

> "checks to see if the object is nonzero"

That is not a correct statement. The `basic_ios` class template (from which the `basic_istream` template inherits) has a conversion operator that allows for testing it in conditions. In particular, pre C++11, they implement an implicit conversion to `void*` that will return either 0 if the stream is in an invalid state or a different value otherwise. That is **not** the object, but an artificial value generated for this purpose. In C++11 the conversion is an explicit conversion to `bool` (and the test `f == 0` will fail)